# Processing.js a way to create JSON

Tags: javascript, json, processing.js

Is there some kind of constructor or some way to create Json object in processing.js? I know that in the Processing library have `JSONObject` but in the processing.js there is nothing like that everything that I found for processing.js is how to **load** JSON but I need some kind of way to create it. If there is way can someone show me how to do it.

Comment: Can you not just use `JSON.stringify`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSONObject` is used by Java (or Processing in Java mode) to create JSON Strings that can be used by JavaScript.

Processing.js is already JavaScript, so you don't need to go through all that trouble.

If you have an object in JavaScript (and Processing.js is already JavaScript), then you can just use the [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function that's built in to JavaScript (and Processing.js).

But again, you might not even need to do this. Processing.js is already JavaScript, so you can probably just use the objects directly in JavaScript code without converting them to JSON first.

Comment: I think that i'll have to use `JSON.stringify` because i am trying to do something like  two factor autentication, i got form with objects and i wanna make array with JSON objects where every object has it's own ID and position codes (like X and Y for example) and when user is ready with his "graphicks password" and when press the button all the data from the array is send to a server and checked for match in the database.

Comment: @MimiChan Yeah, submitting to forms is a good reason to use JSON. But the moral of the story is that if you're working in JavaScript, you don't need to go through `JSONObject` to get to JSON. Just use `JSON.stringify()` instead.